# PHP shell_exec - error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: php, linux, shell

i will start a .sh file in php with shell_exec.

```
$out = array();
exec("/home/user/html/run.sh 2>&1", $out);
print_r($out);
```

in this .sh file there is a programm that will generate a output file on hard disk.

because i got this error back.

**run.sh: line 1: 59934 Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

what does it mean?

Comment: Can you run `/home/user/html/run.sh` from a regular shell? It seems like something in that script is crashing, not the PHP script itself.

Comment: show what's in run.sh. this is not a php error.

Comment: sorry i can not test per SSH logon, because i does not have the username and password for that server.

BECAUSE:
when i edit the "run.sh" and write a "ls" command in that file and start my php script, so everything works fine and i become the right string in $out back.